# Updating two tables with one query depending on the outcome of a third table join MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to update two tables with one query depending on the outcome of a join with another table.

I have a tblPermutations that needs to be checked against a tblDictionary and the ones that match needs to be marked as processed and inserted in a third tblSpellathon.

I've tried the following with no success.

```
UPDATE tblspellathon AS s, 
(SELECT p.*
FROM tblpermutations p
INNER JOIN tbldictionary AS d ON d.Word = p.Permu AND p.`Language` = d.Lang
WHERE d.correct = -1 AND p.PermuProcessed = 0) AS p
SET p.PermuProcessed = -1, s.DerWord = p.Permu, s.WordListID = p.WordListID;
```

and

```
UPDATE tblspellathon AS s, tblpermutations AS p, tbldictionary AS d
SET p.PermuProcessed = -1, s.DerWord = p.Permu, s.WordListID = p.WordListID
WHERE p.permu = d.Word AND p.`Language` = d.Lang AND d.correct = -1 AND 
p.PermuProcessed = 0;
```

On both the above queries I get:

```
SQL Error (1205): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction 
Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec.
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the joining key  with this tblspellathon  table to others?

Comment: Maybe you stop using the old ansi 86/96 comma join and use proper join syntax always. then you might get a shock you make a mistake and you written a Cartesian Product (CROSS JOIN) between the `a and d and p and d` aliases with your comma join syntax

Comment: .. Also questions about performance should provide table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question and the `EXPLAIN <query>` output.. And read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) so we can verify our query results

Comment: You need a joining condition for `tblspellathon`, otherwise it tries to set every row in the table.

Comment: Are you sure you should be updating `tblspellathon`? The question text says it needs to insert into it, not update it.

Comment: you can't do an insert and update in the same query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No. He wants to insert in one table and update another table, not insert or update in the same table.